# this not hitting with selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my js. - .minidiv not hiding and showing

```
var accordion_head = $('.global_right_wrapper .stickySection-a .sticky-close');
accordion_head.on('click', function (event) {
var $a = $(this);
event.preventDefault();

if ($a.hasClass('active')) {
  $(".minidiv", $a).show(); // this is not working****
    $a.removeClass('active').siblings('.content').slideUp();

}

else {
  $(".minidiv", $a).hide(); // this is not working****
    $a.addClass('active').siblings('.content').slideDown();

} });
```

This is my html. - .minidiv not hiding and showing

```
    <div id="stickyFooter-a" class="global_right_wrapper">
    <div class="stickySection-a">
    <h2>WHAT IS JANUVIA®?</h2><span class="sticky-close"><h2>[open]</h2></span>
    <div class="minidiv">JANUVIA (jah-NEW-vee-ah) is a once-daily prescription pill that, along with diet and exercise, 
          <span class="desktopContent">helps lower blood sugar levels in adults with type 2 diabetes.</span>
    </div>
        <div class="content">
             <P>JANUVIA (jah-NEW-vee-ah) is a once-daily prescription pill that, along with diet and exercise, helps lower blood sugar levels in adults with type 2 diabetes.</P>
          <P>JANUVIA should not be used in patients with type 1 diabetes or with diabetic ketoacidosis (increased ketones in the blood or urine). If you have had pancreatitis (inflammation of the pancreas), it is not known if you have a higher chance of getting it while taking JANUVIA.</P>
        </div>
    </div>


   <div class="stickySection-a">
    <h2>IMPORTANT SAFETY INFORMATION</h2><span class="sticky-close"><h2>[open]</h2></span>
        <div class="minidiv">Serious side effects can happen in people who take JANUVIA, including pancreatitis, which may 
          <span class="desktopContent">be severe and lead to death. Before you start taking JANUVIA, tell your doctor if you've ever had pancreatitis. Stop taking JANUVIA and call your doctor right</span>
        </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="mobile-only">
          <p>Serious side effects can happen in people who take JANUVIA, including pancreatitis, which may be severe and lead to death. Before you start taking JANUVIA, tell your doctor if you've ever had pancreatitis. Stop taking JANUVIA and call your doctor right away if you have pain in your stomach area (abdomen) that is severe and will not go away. The pain may be felt going from your abdomen through to your back. The pain may happen with or without vomiting. These may be symptoms of pancreatitis.</p>
          <p>Do not take JANUVIA if you are allergic to any of its ingredients, including sitagliptin. Symptoms of serious allergic reactions to JANUVIA, including rash, hives, and swelling of the face, lips, tongue, and throat that may cause difficulty breathing or swallowing, can occur. If you have any symptoms of a serious allergic reaction, stop taking JANUVIA and call your doctor right away.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="desktop-only">
        <p>Serious side effects can happen in people who take JANUVIA, including pancreatitis, which may be severe and lead to death. Before you start taking JANUVIA, tell your doctor if you've ever had pancreatitis. Stop taking JANUVIA and call your doctor right away if you have pain in your stomach area (abdomen) that is severe and will not go away. The pain may be felt going from your abdomen through to your back. The pain may happen with or without vomiting. These may be symptoms of pancreatitis.</p>
        <p>Do not take JANUVIA if you are allergic to any of its ingredients, including sitagliptin. Symptoms of serious allergic reactions to JANUVIA, including rash, hives, and swelling of the face, lips, tongue, and throat that may cause difficulty breathing or swallowing, can occur. If you have any symptoms of a serious allergic reaction, stop taking JANUVIA and call your doctor right away.</p>
        <p>Kidney problems, sometimes requiring dialysis, have been reported.</p>
        <p>Some people who take medicines called DPP-4 inhibitors like JANUVIA, may develop joint pain that can be severe. Call your doctor if you have severe joint pain.</p>
        <p>If you take JANUVIA with another medicine that can cause low blood sugar (hypoglycemia), such as a sulfonylurea or insulin, your risk of getting low blood sugar is higher. The dose of your sulfonylurea medicine or insulin may need to be lowered while you use JANUVIA. Signs and symptoms of low blood sugar may include headache, drowsiness, weakness, dizziness, confusion, irritability, hunger, fast heart beat, sweating, and feeling jittery.</p>
        <p>Your doctor may do blood tests before and during treatment with JANUVIA to see how well your kidneys are working. Based on these results, your doctor may change your dose of JANUVIA. The most common side effects of JANUVIA are upper respiratory tract infection, stuffy or runny nose and sore throat, and headache.</p>
        <p>You are encouraged to report negative side effects of prescription drugs to the FDA. Visit  <a href="http://www.fda.gov/medwatch">http://www.fda.gov/medwatch</a> or call 1-800-FDA-1088.</p>
        <p class="sect-para">Please read the accompanying <a href="http://doctor.merck.com/product/usa/pi_circulars/j/januvia/januvia_mg.pdf" target="_blank">Medication Guide</a> for JANUVIA® (sitagliptin) tablets and discuss it with your doctor. The physician <a href="http://doctor.januvia.com/sitagliptin/januvia/consumer/prescribing-information.xhtml" target="_blank">Prescribing Information</a> also is available.</p>
        </div>
        <p class="sect-para1">Having trouble paying for your Merck medicine? Merck may be able to help.  Visit <a href="http://www.merckhelps.com">merckhelps.com </a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`'this'` operator working with other but not when I am hiding and showing the div.
I have added the comment in js code

> "// this is not working"

Comment: are you looking for something like this-http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/akEZGa

Comment: What version of jQuery do you use and do you see you problem in all browsers?

Comment: @NagaSaiA i want to hide nd show only minidiv class. under .sticky-close parent class

Comment: @JeroenHeier am checking in chrome

Comment: @SagarShinde check my answer

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option

```
if ($a.hasClass('active')) {
  $(".minidiv").hide(); // this is not working****
    $a.removeClass('active').siblings('.content').slideUp();

}

else {
  $(".minidiv").show(); // this is not working****
    $a.addClass('active').siblings('.content').slideDown();

} });
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/akEZGa

Comment: this code is not for my scenario . I want this child div to be hide on which div i am clicking on.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$a` ie. `$(this)` is actaully the `<span class="sticky-close"><h2>[open]</h2></span>`, and by doing`$(".minidiv", $a)` you are searching for a `.minidiv` inside `<span class="sticky-close"><h2>[open]</h2></span>` which will give back nothing.

Replace

```
$(".minidiv", $a).show();
```

with

```
$(".minidiv", $a.parent()).show();
```

```js
var accordion_head = $('.global_right_wrapper .stickySection-a .sticky-close');
accordion_head.on('click', function(event) {
  var $a = $(this);
  event.preventDefault();

  if ($a.hasClass('active')) {
    $(".minidiv", $a.parent()).show(); // this is not working****
    $a.removeClass('active').siblings('.content').slideUp();

  } else {
    $(".minidiv", $a.parent()).hide(); // this is not working****
    $a.addClass('active').siblings('.content').slideDown();

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="stickyFooter-a" class="global_right_wrapper">
  <div class="stickySection-a">
    <h2>WHAT IS JANUVIA®?</h2><span class="sticky-close"><h2>[open]</h2></span>
    <div class="minidiv">JANUVIA (jah-NEW-vee-ah) is a once-daily prescription pill that, along with diet and exercise,
      <span class="desktopContent">helps lower blood sugar levels in adults with type 2 diabetes.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <P>JANUVIA (jah-NEW-vee-ah) is a once-daily prescription pill that, along with diet and exercise, helps lower blood sugar levels in adults with type 2 diabetes.</P>
      <P>JANUVIA should not be used in patients with type 1 diabetes or with diabetic ketoacidosis (increased ketones in the blood or urine). If you have had pancreatitis (inflammation of the pancreas), it is not known if you have a higher chance of getting
        it while taking JANUVIA.</P>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="stickySection-a">
    <h2>IMPORTANT SAFETY INFORMATION</h2><span class="sticky-close"><h2>[open]</h2></span>
    <div class="minidiv">Serious side effects can happen in people who take JANUVIA, including pancreatitis, which may
      <span class="desktopContent">be severe and lead to death. Before you start taking JANUVIA, tell your doctor if you've ever had pancreatitis. Stop taking JANUVIA and call your doctor right</span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="mobile-only">
        <p>Serious side effects can happen in people who take JANUVIA, including pancreatitis, which may be severe and lead to death. Before you start taking JANUVIA, tell your doctor if you've ever had pancreatitis. Stop taking JANUVIA and call your doctor
          right away if you have pain in your stomach area (abdomen) that is severe and will not go away. The pain may be felt going from your abdomen through to your back. The pain may happen with or without vomiting. These may be symptoms of pancreatitis.</p>
        <p>Do not take JANUVIA if you are allergic to any of its ingredients, including sitagliptin. Symptoms of serious allergic reactions to JANUVIA, including rash, hives, and swelling of the face, lips, tongue, and throat that may cause difficulty breathing
          or swallowing, can occur. If you have any symptoms of a serious allergic reaction, stop taking JANUVIA and call your doctor right away.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="desktop-only">
        <p>Serious side effects can happen in people who take JANUVIA, including pancreatitis, which may be severe and lead to death. Before you start taking JANUVIA, tell your doctor if you've ever had pancreatitis. Stop taking JANUVIA and call your doctor
          right away if you have pain in your stomach area (abdomen) that is severe and will not go away. The pain may be felt going from your abdomen through to your back. The pain may happen with or without vomiting. These may be symptoms of pancreatitis.</p>
        <p>Do not take JANUVIA if you are allergic to any of its ingredients, including sitagliptin. Symptoms of serious allergic reactions to JANUVIA, including rash, hives, and swelling of the face, lips, tongue, and throat that may cause difficulty breathing
          or swallowing, can occur. If you have any symptoms of a serious allergic reaction, stop taking JANUVIA and call your doctor right away.</p>
        <p>Kidney problems, sometimes requiring dialysis, have been reported.</p>
        <p>Some people who take medicines called DPP-4 inhibitors like JANUVIA, may develop joint pain that can be severe. Call your doctor if you have severe joint pain.</p>
        <p>If you take JANUVIA with another medicine that can cause low blood sugar (hypoglycemia), such as a sulfonylurea or insulin, your risk of getting low blood sugar is higher. The dose of your sulfonylurea medicine or insulin may need to be lowered
          while you use JANUVIA. Signs and symptoms of low blood sugar may include headache, drowsiness, weakness, dizziness, confusion, irritability, hunger, fast heart beat, sweating, and feeling jittery.</p>
        <p>Your doctor may do blood tests before and during treatment with JANUVIA to see how well your kidneys are working. Based on these results, your doctor may change your dose of JANUVIA. The most common side effects of JANUVIA are upper respiratory
          tract infection, stuffy or runny nose and sore throat, and headache.</p>
        <p>You are encouraged to report negative side effects of prescription drugs to the FDA. Visit <a href="http://www.fda.gov/medwatch">http://www.fda.gov/medwatch</a> or call 1-800-FDA-1088.</p>
        <p class="sect-para">Please read the accompanying <a href="http://doctor.merck.com/product/usa/pi_circulars/j/januvia/januvia_mg.pdf" target="_blank">Medication Guide</a> for JANUVIA® (sitagliptin) tablets and discuss it with your doctor. The physician <a href="http://doctor.januvia.com/sitagliptin/januvia/consumer/prescribing-information.xhtml"
          target="_blank">Prescribing Information</a> also is available.</p>
      </div>
      <p class="sect-para1">Having trouble paying for your Merck medicine? Merck may be able to help. Visit <a href="http://www.merckhelps.com">merckhelps.com </a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```